# How to wrap function in haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
addMod26 a b = (a + b) `mod` 26
char2Int c = ord c - (ord 'a')
int2Char i = chr (i + (ord 'a'))
addChar a b = int2Char ((addMod26 `on` char2Int) a b)
```

This code try to implement `add` operation on `char`. It work well. But function `addChar` is too redundancy. How to simplify it?

try to write like this

```
addChar = int2Char . (addMod26 `on` char2Int)
```

It's wrong. `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` cannot accept `(b -> b -> c)` as it's first argument.

any good idea, or suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write `addChar` in point-free form, it would be:

```
addChar = (int2Char .) . (addMod26 `on` char2Int)
```

Or:

```
addChar = int2Char .: (addMod26 `on` char2Int)
```

Where `(.:) = (.) . (.)`, which composes a unary function with a binary function:

```
(.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
```

You can discover these refactorings using the [`pointfree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree) tool, although its results tend to be ugly.

Comment: Thanks! I added a function like `.:` by this style `(.:) f g a b = f (g a b)`, but your solution is better, and `.:` is vivid.